# Show a inequality in homogeneous Besov space

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis, besov-spaces

How to prove
$$ \lVert uv\rVert_{\dot{B}^{\frac{N}{p}-1}_{p,1}}\leqslant C \lVert u\rVert_{\dot{B}^{\frac{N}{p}}_{p,1}} \lVert v\rVert_{\dot{B}^{\frac{N}{p}-1}_{p,1}}$$

when $N\geqslant2 $and$1\leqslant p<2N$.

I know it needs Bony decomposition, but I don’t know how to use the condition $N\geqslant2 $and$1\leqslant p<2N$. I could handle the paraproduct. But when dealing with the remainder, I have to assume $p\geqslant2 $and$p<2N$ instead of $N\geqslant2 $.

Any hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shall write $\mathrm{P}_k$ for the homogeneous Littlewood-Paley projectors, and the paraproduct decomposition as

$$ uv = u\prec v + u\succ v + u\diamond v $$

Assume $1\le p<2$. Then $p'>p$ and Bernstein applies to estimate the $L^{p'}_x$ norm in terms of the $L^p_x$ norm, at a cost of derivatives. The resonant term $u\diamond v$ can be estimated as follows.

$$\begin{aligned}
2^{(\frac Np-1)k}\left\|\mathrm{P}_k(u\diamond v)\right\|_{L^p_x}
&\lesssim
2^{(N-1)k}\left\|\mathrm{P}_k(u\diamond v)\right\|_{L^1_x}
\\&\lesssim
2^{(N-1)k}\sum_{\substack{k_*\in\mathbb{Z}\,:\\k_*\ge k-O(1)}}
\left\|\mathrm{P}_{k_*}u\right\|_{L^{p'}_x}
\left\|\mathrm{P}_{\approx k_*}v\right\|_{L^p_x}
\\&\lesssim
2^{(N-1)k}\sum_{\substack{k_*\in\mathbb{Z}\,:\\k_*\ge k-O(1)}}
2^{(\frac Np-\frac N{p'})k_*}\left\|\mathrm{P}_{k_*}u\right\|_{L^p_x}
\left\|\mathrm{P}_{\approx k_*}v\right\|_{L^p_x}
\\&\approx
\sum_{\substack{k_*\in\mathbb{Z}\,:\\k_*\ge k-O(1)}}
2^{(N-1)(k-k_*)}
\left(2^{\frac Npk_*}\left\|\mathrm{P}_{k_*}u\right\|_{L^p_x}\right)
\left(2^{(\frac Np-1)k_*}\left\|\mathrm{P}_{\approx k_*}v\right\|_{L^p_x}\right)
\;.\end{aligned} $$

Because $N-1>0$, we may apply Young's convolution inequality on $\mathbb{Z}$ to obtain

$$ \begin{aligned}
\left\|u\diamond v\right\|_{\dot{B}^{\frac Np-1}_{p,1}}
&\lesssim
\sum_{k_*\in\mathbb{Z}}
\left(2^{\frac Npk_*}\left\|\mathrm{P}_{k_*}u\right\|_{L^p_x}\right)
\left(2^{(\frac Np-1)k_*}\left\|\mathrm{P}_{\approx k_*}v\right\|_{L^p_x}\right)
\\&\lesssim
\left\|u\right\|_{\dot{B}^{\frac Np}_{p,1}}
\left\|v\right\|_{\dot{B}^{\frac Np}_{p,1}}
\;.\end{aligned} $$

Comment: @ Zhuo Min Harold Lim  Thanks a lot! Since I notice there is some difference between your notation and mine, I want to ask which book are you referring? I learn this from “Fourier Analysis and Nonlinear PDEs “by H.Bahouri and J.Y.Chemin, and there aren’t much details.

Comment: @Littlewood There's no standard notation for Littlewood-Paley projectors, the symbol $\mathrm{P}_k$ is quite commonly used in the small part of the dispersive PDE / gauge theory literature I'm familiar with. I too learnt from Bahouri-Chemin-Danchin (mainly Chapters 1, 2, 8) but I decided I did not like using $\Delta$ for Littlewood-Paley projectors when the Laplacian appears in the same equation.

Comment: Thanks! Can you recommend some material about introductory gauge theory for me? Since I am a undergraduate(who is also interested in physics) , I really want to learn as much as possible.

Comment: @Littlewood Sorry for the late reply. About further reading, please PM me to discuss further, as it's not relevant to the post.